# avoid three finger pinching in UIPinchGestureRecognizer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipinchgesturerecognizer

According to apple documentation pinching is a continuous gesture & mean to be use with two fingers. Even with three finger pinching it seems working fine in swift 4.1.

I tried to print number of touches. Even with three fingers it gives number of touches as 2. It seems it detects first 2 finger touches and ignore third.So no way to filter.

```
@objc func pinch(pinchGesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
  if pinchGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
    print("number of touches:\(pinchGesture.numberOfTouches)")
  }
}
```

I am calling setupGesture() method in viewDidLoad. So it handles relevant user pinch gestures.

```
func setupGestures(){

        let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pinch))
        pinch.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)

    }
```

Is there any possible way to avoid three finger pinching in ios?

Comment: What is `pinch` in your code? It's not delegate method... It's event handler? Can you show how it's called/ connected to creation of GestureRecognizer.

Comment: yeah sure. Edited. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter touches in:

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, 
         with event: UIEvent)
```

For example get number of touches from argument `touches` and if `touches.count > 2` then don't act on this gesture - ignore it.

**EDIT(1):**

After your edit I have another idea (I don't have Mac with me, so I can't try this right now). Try to use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer) from delegate. You should be able to get touch before accepting. I don't see information if this will be called once, or one for each touch (each finger). Maybe you can use it in some way?

Comment: Btw I am using gesture recognizers (UIPinchGestureRecognizer) not the touch event .I tried what you sugest earlier. But even with 3 fingers, number of touches ( pinchGesture.numberOfTouches) shows as 2. That means it consider first two fingers and ignore the third fingure touch. So it seems it works for three finger touch.

Comment: @user8028778 Please try my edit. I can't test it right now, but maybe it will help.

Comment: I tried to use this delegate method too. But it's called before touch begin(as declared in apple documentation). So gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches is always zero as it is called before touch begin.

Comment: If so, you maybe need to subclass `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and change logic in `touchesBegin`. I guess changes would be minimal and it shouldn't be hard. I can try to test it in few hours if you can't to solve it on your own.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982409/three-finger-pinch-gesture

Comment: I figured out a way. Your sugestions helps.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I figured out an approach to this problem.This might not be the best solution or can be alternatives. But it works.

Here I just keep an boolean

```
 var numberOfAllTouchesLessThanOrEqualsToTwo = false
```

I used event handler to set boolean value.

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,with event: UIEvent?){

            if (event?.allTouches?.count)! > 2 {
                numberOfAllTouchesLessThanOrEqualsToTwo = false
            }else{
                numberOfAllTouchesLessThanOrEqualsToTwo = true
            }

        }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            if (event?.allTouches?.count)! > 2 {
                numberOfAllTouchesLessThanOrEqualsToTwo = false
            }else{
                numberOfAllTouchesLessThanOrEqualsToTwo = true
            }

        }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            if (event?.allTouches?.count)! > 2 {
                numberOfAllTouchesLessThanOrEqualsToTwo = false
            }else{
                numberOfAllTouchesLessThanOrEqualsToTwo = true
            }
        }
```

and I used this boolean inside gesture recognizer.

```
@objc func pinch(pinchGesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){

     if pinchGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
          if numberOfAllTouchesLessThanOrEqualsToTwo {
            //code
          }
      }
 }
```

It works.